# Default Value of ComboBox based on a property

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have a databound ComboBox as follows:

```
     <ComboBox x:Name="MyEmployee" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource={Binding Path=MyEmployeeList}"/>
```

The DataContext looks like this:

```
MyDataContext = new DataContext
{
  MyEmployeeList = {
  new Employee{ Name = "Vishnu", Id = 1 },
  new Employee{ Name = "Satyam", Id = 2 },
  },

  PermanentEmployee = "Vishnu";
};
```

I would like to be able to set a default value of the ComboBox based on the value of another property: "PermanentEmployee".

It can safely be assumed that "PermanentEmployee" will be among one of the "Name" property in the "EmployeeList".

How do I set such a default value for the ComboBox ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `SelectedItem`, or `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath`

Since WPF compares objects by reference, `SelectedValue` will only work if the `.Equals()` of item is true, so if you're comparing objects then you have to have your `SelectedItem` point to the exact same reference in memory as the item in the `ItemsSource`. For example,

```
MyEmployeeList = {
    new Employee{ Name = "Vishnu", Id = 1 },
    new Employee{ Name = "Satyam", Id = 2 },
};

// Won't work
PermanentEmployee = new Employee{ Name = "Vishnu", Id = 1 };

// Works
PermanentEmployee = MyEmployeeList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Vishnu");
```

Based on the code you showed in your question, you're best off with `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyEmployee" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyEmployeeList}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding PermanentEmployee}"
          SelectedValuePath="Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the SelectedValue property, example:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyEmployee" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyEmployeeList}" Height="25" Width="50" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=PermanentEmployee}"/>
```

Modified:

Correct missed that, in the view model make the PermanentEmployee a Employee data type. Example:

```
   public Employee PermanentEmployee
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Then in your constructor do the following:

PermanentEmployee = MyEmployeeList.Where(r => r.Name == "Vishnu").Single();

Comment: The suggestion does not work. The DataBinding does not show any errors in the output window. In the XAML ComboBox element, SelectedValue will point to the individual items to MyEmployeeList as its DataContext. I believe that's why your suggestion will not work.